# How can I get windows system version using a web page?

Tags: javascript, windows, operating-system, user-agent

How can I get windows system version using a web page?

details system version

such: 19043.1110
[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/modGz.jpg)

Comment: That is not exposed to javascript by browsers

Comment: Is browsing related to the browser or to the OS? The pages depend on the browser and not on the OS. So OS does not need and should not be exposed to the web. If you have LAN and have admin access to the target PCs, then you can find the OS version via PowerShell. Best option- get the i fo from the AD.  I think platform and user agent are also too much informarion disclosure.